# Error Using Renderscript api11+ with support v8

Tags: android, blur, renderscript

I am implementing Blur using RenderScript from support v8. But I am unable to compile the program.

I am getting this error

```
[2015-01-08 15:04:09 - Dex Loader] Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/v8/renderscript/Allocation$1;
[2015-01-08 15:04:09 - HairBusinessApp] Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/v8/renderscript/Allocation$1;
```

My project.properties file contains---

```
target=android-20
android.library.reference.1=../Simple Facebook
android.library.reference.2=../libraryPullToRefersh
android.library.reference.3=../android-support-v7-appcompat
android.library.reference.4=../google-play-services_lib
renderscript.target=18
renderscript.support.mode=true
sdk.buildtools=20
```

If I run this as a demo I am able to run it. But when I try to integrate in my app, it doesnot compile.

Please suggest me what am I doing wrong here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't add your jar in libs folder place your jar to other project like appcompat libs folder and then just add externally that jar to your project by following these steps :-

1) Right click on project Go to properties

2) Select java build path

3) Select libraries tab

4) Choose first option (Add Jar) and then select that jar you placed in appcompat or any other project